# Reading binary files

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, eof

I've to read data from binary file.
This binary data format is:
0x00 0x00 0x01 - is delimiter
after this delimiter there is raw data byte array.
So, to sum up, my binary file looks like:

> 0x00 0x00 0x01 (here is raw data byte)
>   0x00 0x00 0x01 (here is another block
>   of raw data bytes) 0x00 0x00 0x01 ....

So i've wrote such code to parse my file (I'm not very familiar with C)

```
ifstream inp("myfile.bin",ios::binary);
char b1, b2, b3;
while (!inp.eof())
    {
        inp.read(&b1,sizeof(b1));
        inp.read(&b2,sizeof(b2));
        inp.read(&b3,sizeof(b3));
        //finding first delimiter (data starts from delimiter)
        while (!((0==b1)&&(0==b2)&&(1==b3)))
        {
            b1=b2;
            b2=b3;
            if (inp.eof())
                break;      
            inp.read(&b3,sizeof(b3));
        }
        if (inp.eof())
            break;              
        char* raw=new char[65535];
        int rawSize=0;

        inp.read(&b1,sizeof(b1));
        inp.read(&b2,sizeof(b2));
        inp.read(&b3,sizeof(b3));

        raw[rawSize++]=b1;
        raw[rawSize++]=b2;
        if (inp.eof())
            break;  

        //reading raw data until delimiter is found
        while (!((0==b1)&&(0==b2)&&(1==b3)))
        {
            raw[rawSize++]=b3;
            b1=b2;
            b2=b3;
            if (inp.eof())
                break;      
            inp.read(&b3,sizeof(b3));
        }
        rawSize-=2; //because of two bytes of delimiter (0x00 0x00) would be added to raw

        //Do something with raw data

        if (inp.eof())
            break;

        inp.putback(1);
        inp.putback(0);
        inp.putback(0);

        delete []raw;
    }
```

But sometimes this code falls into infinite loop.
Could you advice me something?
Thanks

Comment: way too much `C++`, consider removing the `C` tag

Comment: eof is there to find out the cause of a failed read, not to predict that the next read will fail because of the end of file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a file twice in C++ because of eof ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684537/read-a-file-twice-in-c-because-of-eof)

Comment: So what should I do in my situation?

Comment: In fact, I've noticed that program falls into infinite loop nearly in the middle of the binary file....not in the end of file

Comment: In the middle of my file code thinks that found 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1.... but in fact there is 0 0 1 (raw data) 0 0 1.... I'm feeling mixed-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem there is that `putback` fails. As far as i recall, `putback` is guaranteed to work only once; second invocation will fail if the internal read buffer is aligned (that is, very rarely; seems like your situation).

To fix, get rid of `putback`. First of all, move the loop commented as "finding first delimiter" out of the outer `while` loop: the comment suggests that this code should only run once. After you do it, pay attention that at the beginning of the outer `while` loop, the sequence `0x00 0x00 0x01` has just been found, so the code doesn't have to use `putback` and look for it again.

Answer (score 0):

- You're using `feof()` wrong, it's only valid *after* a read has been attempted and failed.
- How do you know that your magic byte sequence 0 0 1 doesn't appear inside the data? If the data is just a "binary array" that doesn't sound like it provides much of a guarantee ...

Comment: Exactly known that byte sequence 0 0 1 doesn't appear inside the data. In fact, I've noticed that program falls infinite loop nearly in the middle of the binary file....